# Trouble moving CollectionViewCell to the end

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UICollectionView` in a `UIViewController`. I've configured a gesture recognizer to move cells. It works fine for moving a cell to any index except the end. Most aggravatingly, the app doesn't crash when I attempt to move a cell to the end--it just hangs. I can back out of `ReorderViewController`and go back to it. The view reloads normally.

I call this method from `viewDidLoad` to configure the gesture recognizer:

```
func configureGestureRecognizer() {
    // configure longPressGestureRecognizer
    longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ReorderViewController.handleLongPressGesture))
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
    longPressGesture.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
}
```

When the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is triggered, its handler is called:

```
func handleLongPressGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let selectedIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: self.collectionView)) else {
        return
    }
    let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)

    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
        print("began")
        editMode = true
        collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
        selectedCell?.isSelected = true
    case .changed:
        editMode = true
        selectedCell?.isSelected = true
        print("changed")
        collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: self.collectionView))
    case .ended:
        print("ended")
        editMode = false
        selectedCell?.isSelected = false
        collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
    default:
        print("default")
        editMode = false
        selectedCell?.isSelected = false
        collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}
```

I can move cells with the gesture without any trouble so long as I'm not moving one to the end. Most annoyingly, the app doesn't crash--it just hangs. I can press the "Back" button on the NavBar and go to the prior ViewController without crashing and return to ReorderViewController.

Here's my code for moving cells:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let stuffToReorder = currentRoutine?.myOrderedSet.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableOrderedSet
    stuffToReorder.exchangeObject(at: sourceIndexPath.row, withObjectAt: destinationIndexPath.row)
    currentRoutine?.myOrderedSet = stuffToReorder as NSOrderedSet
    appDelegate.saveContext()
}
```

Any thoughts re: where my mistake is are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Adrian - I've recreated the above in a playground (using NSOrdered set comprising 50 Ints) and it works fine with your code (not really germane to your question but any particular reason you are using NSOrderedSet here?). The only thing I can't recreate is your reference to currentRoutine, and also I'm a bit stumped by your appDelegate.saveContext call. Could you provide a bit more detail on what these are and their role in your project?

Comment: @Sparky Thanks for looking! `currentRoutine` is an NSOrderedSet of NSManagedObjects. I tried it out on a physical device and I'm able to replicate the bug there. The "freeze" only happens if I drag an object well beyond the bounds of the other cells. The `appDelegate.saveContext()` call is to save the NSManagedObject when the order of `myOrderedSet` is changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've cracked it. My hunch about CoreData being the issue was a red herring (which is just as well as I don't have much experience of it!). The hang up was caused by the guard statement at the start of your handler method. Specifically, your method checks that there is a valid index path related to the gesture location; if the gesture moves out of the collection view, I think everything gets confused and therefore you get the hang (rather than a crash) as the function keeps exiting at that point. Moving things around a bit, however, seems to solve the problem:

```
    func handleLongPressGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let _ = collectionVC.collectionView else { return }

        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            guard let selectedIndexPath = collectionVC.collectionView!.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: collectionVC.collectionView)) else { return }
            selectedCell = collectionVC.collectionView!.cellForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
            print("began")
            lastGoodLocation = gesture.location(in: collectionVC.collectionView!)
            collectionVC.collectionView!.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
        selectedCell.isSelected = true

        case .changed:

            selectedCell?.isSelected = true
            if collectionVC.collectionView!.frame.contains(gesture.location(in: view)) {
                print(gesture.location(in: view))
                print(collectionVC.collectionView!.frame)
                print("INSIDE COLLECTION VIEW!")
                collectionVC.collectionView!.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: collectionVC.collectionView!))
                lastGoodLocation = gesture.location(in: collectionVC.collectionView!)
            }
            else
            {
                print("OUTSIDE COLLECTION VIEW!")
                collectionVC.collectionView!.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(lastGoodLocation) // Not sure this is needed
            }
            print("changed")

        case .ended:
            print("ended")

            selectedCell?.isSelected = false
            collectionVC.collectionView!.endInteractiveMovement()

        default:
            print("default")

            selectedCell?.isSelected = false
            collectionVC.collectionView!.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        }
    }
```

Implementing things this way, I moved the guard statement for selectedCell into the .began case of your switch, as this is the only place that it is initialised. I therefore had to declare selectedCell as a class property so that it could be referenced within the other cases later on. I also introduced a CGPoint variable, lastGoodLocation, which stores the last location for which a valid index path is available - this way, if the gesture ends outside the collection view, the cell is sent to that index path.

Anyway, this is a bit rough but certainly seems to prevent the hang. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! That was it! I declared `var lastGoodLocation: CGPoint?` at the top of the class. Then I changed `case .changed:` to be an `if-else`. Very simple solution. For those following at home, I took out `selectedCell?.isSelected = true` in `case .changed:` so every cell the user drags over doesn't get selected, too.